# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: magento2, php-7, magento2.3.3, dom

How to solve this issue? DOM extension enabled in cPanel.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/freshvcf/public_html/test/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:449

Magento 2 command is not working properly

[image]

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/bigshopnz/public\_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:388](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306113/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-domdocument-not-found-in-home-bigshopnz-pu)

Answer (score 0):

Run this commands and try again :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-imap
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Install DOM Extension .

```
apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

Change PHP version according server PHP version