# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:388

Tags: magento2.3

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:388
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(116): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<?xml version="...')
#1 /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<?xml version="...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, 'xsi:type', NULL)
#2 /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(151): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom->_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '<?xml version="...')
#3 /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(132): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#4 /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ in /home/bigshopnz/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 388
```

Can you please let me know the proper solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

> You need to install dom extension, Run below commands

```
apt-get install php-xml
service apache2 restart
```

**Hope it helps.**

Answer (score 0):

**PHP 7.0**:

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php7.0-xml`
- CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat: `yum install php70w-xml`

**PHP 7.1**:

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php7.1-xml`
- CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat: `yum install php71w-xml`

**PHP 7.2**:

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php7.2-xml`
- CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat: `yum install php72w-xml`

**PHP 7.3**:

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php7.3-xml`
- CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat: `yum install php73w-xml`

**PHP 7.4**:

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php7.4-xml`
- CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat: `yum install php74w-xml`